# How do I center the logo and contact form on my website

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve here is to center my logo and my contact form. I have tried looking on google and here but found nothing that will help. I will include a js bin please anyone help me.

https://jsbin.com/foqemipeco/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2):

Add a `display: inline-block` and `margin: 0 56px` to `#logo` for the logo centering. Then, add a `display: inline-block` to `#box-header`, and `margin: 45px 115px 0` to `#box` for the form centering.

I use the `inline-block` trick to bound the main container size to the size of the elements within it. By cutting the size you become able to center the container with lateral margins. Also, it's not really necessary to define the width in `#box`, and using `<br>` tags for layouts is a really bad practice, get rid of them, the margin I provided for that container will push it down.

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: Just copy-paste the HTML and CSS sections of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sys2he6o/) Fiddle in your Jsbin, the three stated changes can be found at the bottom of the CSS code.